# Right leg becoming sore after swimming 1000m

Tags: swimming, routine, soreness

I have been swimming in pool for about close to a year now. I'm able to swim freestyle  500m in 30 mins in easy pace. (I don't know if it is good or needs improvement).
The next 500m I intend to train my legs and shoulders for kick and pull.
So I do 50m kickboard - 100m pull until I reach 500m mark.  The overall routine looks like this.

```
| Activity  | Distance | Remarks  |
|-----------+----------+----------|
| freestyle | 500m     | 25m X 20 |
| kickboard | 50m      | 25m X 2  |
| Pull      | 100m     | 50m X 2  |
| kickboard | 50m      | 25m X 2  |
| Pull      | 100m     | 50m X 2  |
| kickboard | 50m      | 25m X 2  |
| Pull      | 100m     | 50m X 2  |
| kickboard | 50m      | 25m X 2  |
```

I have been doing this routine since August 2017 - all days except Mondays.
**Question:**
After the swimming session, my right thigh is sore and there is calf pain as well. Why is this happening and *more importantly how can I overcome this*?

**P.S:**
I'm training myself to become a triathlete and I'm learning swimming for this reason

Comment: Are you pushing of the wall really hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question, 500m in 30 minutes is slightly faster than floating with the waves, unfortunately. Top high school boys will be near 4:30 (4 minutes 30 seconds) for that distance, girls will be 15ish seconds slower.

However, this combined with the leg pain in the kicking portion tells me that most likely you have a form problem, that causes you to use your right leg much more than your left in your swimming stroke. Then, when you isolate during the kicking, it is more fatigued than your left.

I would have two recommendations for you:

1. Lessons - Get some swim lessons, or at least some time with a decent stroke instructor who can tell you what you can improve on. Ask for specific drills.
2. Workouts - Your workout isn't really structured to make you a better or a faster swimmer. I would look at "Swim workouts in a Binder" in any of the variations (They have one specifically for triathletes) to get an idea of what a swim workout would look like.

Once you get your (suspected) form issues cleaned up and get some good structure to your workouts, your times will drop dramatically. It will also improve your triathlon times, as you won't get out of the water already tired.

Comment: The HS times are for short course yards, not short course meters.

Comment: @JonCuster you are correct. Add 25ish seconds to get scm, slightly less for lcm vs tge scy time. My mistake on not clarifying.